# Getting error while starting hadoop

Tags: apache, networking, hadoop, client-server

I have Hadoop 0.20 , i am starting it by running $HADOOP/bin/start-all.sh.
Every demon is running but while datanode it throws error

> localhost: Unrecognized option: -jvm 
>   localhost: Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. 
>   localhost: Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

But i have installed java.

> [root@ulhshr1ld1 bin]# java -version 
>   java version "1.7.0_01"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_01-b08)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 21.1-b02, mixed mode)

And i am also able to access **http://localhost:50070/dfshealth.jsp** And **http://localhost:50030/jobtracker.jsp**

Can any one please guide me whats is the problem?

Comment: this should be migrated to Serverfault

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug in Hadoop when run as root. It has been fixed in the newer releases. Here is the [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-1943). Use the latest version of Hadoop.

Root gives complete access to the system. Create a separate user and start the daemons. Why start the daemons as root?

Also, Apache [recommends](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.205.0/single_node_setup.html#Required+Software) to use Java 6 from Oracle. Look like you are running Java 7. Hadoop with Java 7 has not been tested thoroughly.

Comment: Ok.Thanks Praveen.I am even not able to run jps command , which is there in jdk 1.5 onwards (as oracle claimed)

Answer (score 3):

The -jvm options should be passed to jsvc when we starting a secure
datanode, but it still passed to java when start-dfs.sh is run by root
while secure datanode is disabled.

This is a bug of bin/hdfs.or bin/hadoop.

apply the following patch.

HDFS-1943 patch.

> diff --git bin/hdfs bin/hdfs index 76ff689..ce9dc0a 100755
>   --- bin/hdfs
>   +++ bin/hdfs @@ -71,7 +71,7 @@ elif [ "$COMMAND" = "secondarynamenode" ] ; then    >HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS $HADOOP_SECONDARYNAMENODE_OPTS" 
>   elif [ "$COMMAND" = "datanode" ] ; then
>   CLASS='org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode'
>   -  if [[ $EUID -eq 0 ]]; then
>   +  if [ "$starting_secure_dn" = "true" ]; then
>        HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -jvm server $HADOOP_DATANODE_OPTS"    else
>        HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -server $HADOOP_DATANODE_OPTS"

copy the above to a file named HDFS.patch.To apply patch run in terminal

> patch -p0  < /path/to/patch/file  /path/to/file/to/be/patched

/path/to/file/to/be/patched will be ../bin/hadoop or .../bin/hdfs