# Hadoop Fail to start - Unrecognized option: -jvm

Tags: hadoop, jvm

I am using hadoop-0.20.203, after did required changes when i start the hdfs it throws following warning while start up

```
root@master:/usr/local/hadoop-0.20.203# bin/start-all.sh 
starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-0.20.203/bin/../logs/hadoop-root-namenode-master.out
master: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-0.20.203/bin/../logs/hadoop-root-datanode-master.out
master: Unrecognized option: -jvm
master: Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
master: Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
master: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-0.20.203/bin/../logs/hadoop-root-secondarynamenode-master.out
starting jobtracker, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-0.20.203/bin/../logs/hadoop-root-jobtracker-master.out
master: starting tasktracker, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-0.20.203/bin/../logs/hadoop-root-tasktracker-master.out
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the script normally as a non-root user. Ensure your non-root user has appropriate permissions. Refer to this bug report for more information

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-1943

Comment: Problem solved, downloaded the HDFS-1943 patch from above and performed command `patch -p0 < /path/to/patch/file /path/to/file/to/be/patched`  refer [HDFS PATCH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8411917/getting-error-while-starting-hadoop)

Answer (score 0):

Use `sudo bin/start-all.sh` and see if it helps. Ideally you should avoid running Hadoop as `root` user.